# Run individual parameterized testcase with nunit-console

Tags: c#, nunit

I can run an individual testcase which takes a single string value with no problems from the command line:

For example `/run:Namespace.Class.Method("my input string")`

However the same procedure doesn't seem to work for me with numerical inputs

For example: `/run:Namespace.Class.Method(1,2,3)`

The output lists the correct input as a 'test to run' but does not actually run any tests

EDIT:

Looking into this further, it appears that the problem is with tests which take more than one argument.  Using the following test file:

```
namespace GetTestsProj
{
    [TestFixture]
    class NunitConsoleTest
    {
        [TestCase(1,2,3)]
        [Test, Description("A simple test with parameterized numeric inputs")]
        public void TestNumeric(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(c, a + b);
        }

        [TestCase("My String")]
        [Test, Description("A simple test with parameterized string input")]
        public void TestSingleString(string a)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("My String", a);
        }
        [TestCase("String1", "String2")]
        [Test, Description("A simple test with parameterized numeric inputs")]
        public void TestTwoStrings(string a, string b)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("String1", a);
        }
    }
}
```

The call `nunit-console.exe /run:GetTestsProj.NunitConsoleTest GetTestsProj\GetTestsProj\bin\debug\GetTestsProj.dll` properly runs all 3 testcases

The call `nunit-console.exe /run:GetTestsProj.NunitConsoleTest.TestNumeric GetTestsProj\GetTestsProj\bin\debug\GetTestsProj.dll` properly runs 1 testcase

The call `nunit-console.exe /run:"GetTestsProj.NunitConsoleTest.TestSingleString(\"My String\")" GetTestsProj\GetTestsProj\bin\debug\GetTestsProj.dll` properly runs 1 testcase

However, the call `nunit-console.exe /run:GetTestsProj.NunitConsoleTest.TestNumeric(1,2,3) GetTestsProj\GetTestsProj\bin\debug\GetTestsProj.dll` runs 0 testcases

And similarly the call `nunit-console.exe /run:"GetTestsProj.NunitConsoleTest.TestTwoStrings(\"String1\",\"String2\")" GetTestsProj\GetTestsProj\bin\debug\GetTestsProj.dll` runs 0 testcases

Although nunit *seems* to recognize the input `/run` properly:

```
Selected test(s): GetTestsProj.NunitConsoleTest.TestNumeric(1,2,3)

Tests run: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```

and

```
Selected test(s): GetTestsProj.NunitConsoleTest.TestTwoStrings("String1", "String2")

Tests run: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.0156256 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```

This is all using NUnit 2.5.9.10348

I'm interested in whether this is user error or unsupported functionality.  It would be very useful for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Since this is presumably a bug, I've submitted this to nunit here: [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/731994) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the list of testcases is split on the ',' character, causing an obvious problem for parameterized testcases.  Bug information is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/731994), and I'll try to post the conclusion on here when there is more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this behavior should be fixed in NUnit 2.6.0 and newer.

If you are still running into this issue like I was (using NUnit 2.6.4 here), then you may need to escape the double-quote characters by putting a backslash in front of them.

Answer (score -2):

Not that it helps your particular problem, but are you aware that ReSharper from JetBrains has an NUnit testrunner for VS? There are probably more tools that have it too. I have Resharper, and have never had the need to run single test from the console since (besides, it has a whole bunch of cool refactoring tools). I hope that this doesn't sound to much like spam. I just wondered why You run single tests from the console.

Comment: I actually do have ReSharper (and it's great), but I'm trying to run these tests in a CI environment, which means I'm limited to the console.  I am also running front end tests which use Selenium.  There are two reasons for running individual Test Cases: 1) Selenium tests have a tendency to hit timeouts or other intermittent issues, and I'd like to be able to rerun failed tests a couple of times, and 2) I'd like to be able to have individual test cases run on separate VM's to help parallelize the process

Comment: Ok, Then I'm afraid that I can be of little help. At my work we run CI as well, but just whole projects at the time, not single tests. Did you think about moving those special test cases into a project of its own, and then run them as usual?